# PHP Obtain Textual Month, Day and Year from input field

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

I have a textual month, day and year in an input field and I'd like to convert it to a date that will later be inserted into a 'date' field within a MySQL Table.

Textual month, day and year from HTML input field: "Aug 25, 2014".

PHP:

```
$time_cell_row = 1;
$time_cell_column = 1;

echo "<form name='timesubmit" . $time_cell_row . "' action='enter_time.php?action=timesubmit" .$time_cell_row . "' method='post'>";  

$todays_date = strtotime("today");  // 
$FormattedCurrDate = date('M d, Y', $todays_date);  // Converts to "Aug 25, 2014"

echo "<th><input name=daycell1 type=text value=" . $FormattedCurrDate . "<disabled /></th>";

// The above echo statement displays "Aug" in a table cell instead of "Aug 25, 2014"

echo "<td><input name=submit_time" . $time_cell_row . $time_cell_column . " type=submit></input></td>";
echo  "</form></tr>";


$date1 = $_POST['daycell1'];  // null 
echo "Date from input field: " . $date1; // Nothing is displayed from $date1 since is null

          echo "<br>";
```

Why is $_POST['daycell1'] showing up as null instead of putting in "Aug 25, 2014"?

Comment: consider the data type of that particular column in your table

Comment: FYI: `<input>` tags are void tags, therefore they have no `</` end tags, use `value="your php variable"` instead

Comment: `echo "<th><input name=daycell1 type=text value=" . $FormattedCurrDate . "<disabled /></th>";` do not use `disabled` attribute, use `readonly` and remove that superfluous `<`

Comment: Putting the variable '$FormattedCurrDate' and changing 'disabled' to 'readonly' made it work!  Now the next part is how do I convert this string 'Aug 25, 2014' into a date so that I can insert it into a MySQL Table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, `$date1` is `null` because you haven't submitted the form yet, so `$_POST['daycell1']` is still undefined upon first load.

`<input />` tags are void tags, they do not have a closing tag. Use the `value=""` attribute if you want them to contain a value.

Do not use the `disabled` attribute. All input tags with the `disabled` attribute will not be included inside `$_POST`. Use `readonly` instead.

```
// defaults to current day
$FormattedCurrDate = date('M d, Y');

echo '<form method="POST">';
    echo '<table><tr>';
        echo "<th><input name='daycell1' type='hidden' value='$FormattedCurrDate' /></th>";
        echo '<td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>';
    echo '</tr></table>';
echo '</form>';

// if submit button is pressed
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $date = $_POST['daycell1']; // assign the hidden tag value to variable
    echo $date;
}
```

The date is truncated because you're missing closing quotes.

```
echo "<th><input name=daycell1 type=text value='" . $FormattedCurrDate . "' /></th>";
                                           //  ^ quotes                   ^ quotes
```

Sidenote: Always turn on **error reporting** on development.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: Putting the form above the code definitely helped, I had that line of code in the wrong place.  The problem now is when I set: echo "<th><input name='daycell1' type='hidden' value='$FormattedCurrDate' /></th>"; ---> The table cell is now blank and when I inspect the element, this is what is displayed: <input name='daycell1' type='hidden' value = 'Aug' 25, 2014>

Comment: @JeffP. what happens? `The problem now is when I set:`? you have to be more specific than that. i can't guess what's happening on your side.

Comment: @JeffP. is this a trick question? haha :D. its supposed to be blank. its a hidden input tag, if you wan't it to be seen, then use `type="text"` instead

Comment: I changed the input type = 'text' and now only 'Aug' is displayed instead of the whole string 'Aug 25, 2014'

Comment: @JeffP. update your question and add your current code that you're using, its working here by the way http://codepad.viper-7.com/8nwyU1, most likely a quoting problem on your `echo`

Comment: nice code style. +1 I would keep the first variable as a lowercase `f` though.